# Is "Hiding Among Zombies" an idea from Walking Dead or has this existed earlier?

Tags: history-of, the-walking-dead, zombie

In the TV series *The Walking Dead*, I've for the first time seen the idea of hiding in hordes of Zombies using some of their traits. In *The Walking Dead*, there are currently two ways to do this:

1. Wear clothes full of Walker blood / innards to have the apparently very distinct smell of Zombies. We see this the first time in the series in S01E02 *Gut*.
2. The Whisperers found their own way by wearing masks of Walkers to hide they haven't turned yet.

[image: Rick and Carl in clothes drenched with Walker Blood. Example for point 1 to avoid Walker recognizing not turned humans]

The only other time I am aware of this happening is in the film *Zombieland* from 2009. Bill Murray (playing himself) uses make up to hide he's still alive and uses this to leave his house, e.g. to play golf.

[image: Bill Murray with Zombie make up]

Technically, *Zombieland* was released earlier than *The Walking Dead*. I haven't read the TWD comics but assume the blood drenched clothes is used there also?! As the comics were released in 2003, TWD still has the first appearance of using disguise to hide among zombies.

What is the first appearance of non-Zombies using any kind of disguise in order to hide that they're still alive from the undead?

Comment: Well *Shaun of the Dead* is 2004, several years earlier than that.

Comment: Are you looking for live-action TV specifically? Or would any media do? And specifically zombies, and not just trying to pass as one of the bad guys?

Comment: They're brainwashed, not undead, but The Mummy (1999) features a person pretending to be part of a mindless, shambling horde.

Comment: Depending on the definition of zombie, you could go back to 1978 and the Invasion of the Body Snatchers, towards the end of that version there is a scene where 2 characters act like the pod people, so as not to be discovered.  The pod people are similar to the original zombie concept from voodoo mythology....

Comment: I've not seen the original version from 1955 nor read the book so can't say for certain that a similar scene doesn't appear in those, but I am sure of the 1978 version.

Comment: Warm Bodies features such a scene but it is from 2013.

Comment: If you take the concept to a higher level, it's "playing dead" in order to avoid some sort of predator/monster, which is a trope used all over the place.

Comment: @fez Sorry for the late answer. Any media is accepted. And yes, Zombies or zombielike creatures. Simply acting as the bad guy is IMHO to wide to be possible to be answered.

Comment: Yeah, pretending to be a zombie is nothing innovative or new.

Comment: "Aren't you a little short for a stormtrooper?" Not a new trope. (And that's hardly the first instance.) I don't think adoption to the zombie genre is particularly significant.

Comment: @ikegami I think it's noteworthy because it seems intuitive that fooling zombies would require very different skills than fooling other living people. It's half-way between trying to fool a human and a society of... I dunno... frog people. If they watch for behaviour, they don't see it the way a living person does. Maybe they hunt by smell. etc. etc. etc.

Comment: If the question was about how it's done, you'd have a point.

Comment: @ikegami I don't think it needs that. We don't expect to be able to fool animals into thinking we're one of them, so why wouldn't it be non-obvious to fool zombies?

Comment: Re "*why wouldn't it be non-obvious to fool zombies?*", I never said it wouldn't??? Noone asked if it was obvious. Noone asked it was easy. Noone asked for examples. Noone asked for the history for hiding from zombies. Noone asked if it had been done. The question is about the first time it was done.

Comment: @ikegami You said "I don't think adoption to the zombie genre is particularly significant." I responded with why zombies occupy an unusual middle-ground between animal and human which makes it special.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[image: Invasion of the Body Snatchers]

You could look at films like Invasion of the Body Snatchers (1957, 1978) where the lead characters act emotionless and dazed to blend in with the replacements/aliens. It's not quite the same, yet it's a similar trope?

Comment: I've just read the synopsis on Wikipedia and I'd say it's close enough to be relevant, yes.

Answer (score 50):

Beating both of your televised examples and possibly the TWD comics would be Shaun of the Dead (2004).

The disguise used is as simple as a slack jawed expression, a shambling walk, and a selection of moans.

There may be earlier examples to be found but given the lead time on movies I believe this would have had to have been written before the comics were released at the very least.

Comment: Well, the comics also had to be drawn, revised etc. Unless there is a script from way before 2004, I'd still say that TWD with 2003 is earlier.

Comment: According to Kirkman's wikipedia page he started TWD "shortly after the launch of Invincible", which was in November 2002. It launched in October 2003.

SotD started filming in May 2003 (after the writing for TWD had started) - but it was based on a script that took 8 weeks to write, and which had been pitched at Cannes in May 2002.

Comment: Does Thriller count?

Comment: I recall the idea of pretending to be a zombie to appear a lot later into the comic, I think many years later. I was actually surprised to see that it happend in the second episode of the show.

Comment: @DannyMcG [Michael was a zombie all along](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sOnqjkJTMaA#t=11m40s).

Comment: @DannyMcG The song by Michael Jackson? Can't remember that he pretends to be a Zombie.

Comment: @VienLa So, SotD definitely was earlier, thanks for that clarification!

Comment: @Schwern Thanks a load there, Captain Spoiler.  By the way, the chick from The Crying Game... is Luke's father!

Answer (score 38):

Not the same kind of zombie, but how about The Mummy (1999)?

Comment: Not the same kind of Zombie but IMHO close enough to be considered, yes.

Comment: You might want to give a bit more detail about the video (the fact that one of the main characters is seen blending into a crowd by chanting like them and taking the same walking pace), in case the video were to disappear

Comment: This is what came to my mind immediately, great find.

Answer (score 16):

I haven't seen this, but [La Invasión de los muertos](http://terpconnect.umd.edu/%7Edwilt/muertos.htm) *released as [The Invasion of the Dead](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0263475) (1973)* supposedly has a scene where

> The soldiers come back as zombies and Blue Demon has to fight them and the monsters (Polo Ortín fools them by pretending to be a zombie himself).

[image: Movie Poster]

Comment: Now that's an alluring poster.

Answer (score 5):

Book Six of Ovid's *Metamorphoses* (year ~8 CE) features Procne rescuing her sister Philomela by disguising herself as a [Maenad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maenad) -- arguably not a zombie, but certainly a follower of the god Bacchus who has been riled into a supernatural, animalistic frenzy and not particularly capable of rational thought. The text describes her need for appropriate dress (vines, animal skins) and behavior (hurtling movements, screaming) to blend in and perform the rescue amid the throng:

> It was the time when the young Thracian women used to celebrate the triennial festival of Bacchus. (Night knew their holy rites: by night, Mount Rhodope rang with the high-pitched clashing of bronze). By night the queen left her palace, prepared herself for the rites of the god, and took up the weapons of that frenzied religion. Tendrils of vine wreathed her head; a deerskin was draped over her left side; a light javelin rested on her shoulder. Hurtling through the woods with a crowd of her companions, terrifying, driven by maddening grief, Procne embodies you, Bacchus. She comes at last to the building in the wilderness, and howls out loud, giving the ecstatic cry of Euhoe, breaks the door down, seizes her sister, disguises her with the tokens of a wild Bacchante, hides her face with ivy leaves, and dragging her along with her, frightened out of her wits, leads her inside the palace walls.

It is worth noting that she isn't rescuing her sister *from* the Maenads, but using the throng as cover against her captor, a normal human man.

While Maenads aren't undead, they do tear people apart limb from limb at multiple points in *Metamorphoses*.

Comment: I'm sure Shaggy and Scooby Doo have done it